# Lost in DateTime in powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime

I somehow is lost in DateTime in Powershell

My Function To validate DateTime. Note It was sleeker but I was lost so started explicit returns of Good Bad. Don't Mind that. I want to capture the  following

1. Start Time and End Time entered is correct (not junk)
2. End Time is bigger than Start Time
3. End Time is larger than current Time in UTC
4. Start Time is larger than current time in UTC

```
function IsValidTimeStamp($startDate,$endDate)
{
    [ref]$parsedDate = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
    if (!([DateTime]::TryParseExact($startDate,"M/d/yy H:mm",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
        [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,$parseddate))){
            return ("Bad")
        }
    elseif(!([DateTime]::TryParseExact($endDate,"M/d/yy H:mm",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
        [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,$parseddate))){
            return ("Bad")
        }
    elseif(!(Get-date $([datetime]::ParseExact($endDate,"M/dd/yy H:mm",$Null))) -gt (Get-Date $([datetime]::ParseExact($startDate,"M/dd/yy H:mm",$Null)))){
            return ("Bad")
        }
    elseif((Get-date $([datetime]::ParseExact($startDate,"M/dd/yy H:mm",$Null))).ToUniversalTime() -gt $([System.DateTime]::UtcNow)){
            return ("Bad")
        }
    elseif((Get-date $([datetime]::ParseExact($endDate,"M/dd/yy H:mm",$Null))).ToUniversalTime() -gt $([System.DateTime]::UtcNow)){
            return ("Bad")
        }
    else
        {return ("Good")}
}
```

Now when I enter the a proper date which is less than current UTC time
$startDate = '03/20/23 14:00' & $endDate = '03/20/23 14:30'
Something is not correct. Most Likely the statement

```
elseif((Get-date $([datetime]::ParseExact($startDate,"M/dd/yy H:mm",$Null))).ToUniversalTime() -gt $([System.DateTime]::UtcNow)){
            return ("Bad")
        }
 elseif((Get-date $([datetime]::ParseExact($endDate,"M/dd/yy H:mm",$Null))).ToUniversalTime() -gt $([System.DateTime]::UtcNow)){
            return ("Bad")
        }
```

Strangely if you see both the results are returning false as even though I am using a not operator

[image: Why the Not Operator has no effect. Both times it is coming false]

I am calling the function like this below

```
 if ((IsValidTimeStamp $($LINE.Start_Time) $($LINE.End_Time)) -eq "Good"){
                #Basic validation of DateTime is successful 
               ###Do something else ###
}
else{
       echo "Failed to validate dateTime"
}
```

As asked below copy pasting the commands ran on the console

```
PS D:\Maintenance-Window> $startDate = '03/20/23 14:00'

PS D:\Maintenance-Window> $endDate = '03/20/23 14:30'

PS D:\Maintenance-Window> [ref]$parsedDate = Get-Date

PS D:\Maintenance-Window> !([DateTime]::TryParseExact($startDate,"M/d/yy H:mm",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
        [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,$parseddate))
False

PS D:\Maintenance-Window> !([DateTime]::TryParseExact($endDate,"M/d/yy H:mm",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
        [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,$parseddate))
False

PS D:\Maintenance-Window> !(Get-date $([datetime]::ParseExact($endDate,"M/dd/yy H:mm",$Null))) -gt `
            (Get-Date $([datetime]::ParseExact($startDate,"M/dd/yy H:mm",$Null)))
False

PS D:\Maintenance-Window> (Get-date $([datetime]::ParseExact($startDate,"M/dd/yy H:mm",$Null))).ToUniversalTime() -gt `
            $([System.DateTime]::UtcNow)
False

PS D:\Maintenance-Window> !(Get-date $([datetime]::ParseExact($startDate,"M/dd/yy H:mm",$Null))).ToUniversalTime() -gt `
            $([System.DateTime]::UtcNow)
False
```

If you look closely the last two commands are exactly the same one with the Not symbol in front. Since the input time has passed than current UTC time I expected a True.

*EDIT Final Script*

```
function IsValidTimeStamp($startDate,$endDate)
{
    [ref]$parsedDate = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
    if (!([DateTime]::TryParseExact($startDate,"M/d/yy H:mm",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
        [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,$parseddate))){
            return ("Bad")
        }
    elseif(!([DateTime]::TryParseExact($endDate,"M/d/yy H:mm",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
        [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,$parseddate))){
            return ("Bad")
        }
    elseif(!((Get-date $([datetime]::ParseExact($endDate,"M/d/yy H:mm",$Null))) -gt (Get-Date $([datetime]::ParseExact($startDate,"M/d/yy H:mm",$Null))))){
            return ("Bad")
        }
    elseif(!((Get-date $([datetime]::ParseExact($startDate,"M/d/yy H:mm",$Null))).ToUniversalTime() -gt $([System.DateTime]::UtcNow))){
            return ("Bad")
        }
    elseif(!((Get-date $([datetime]::ParseExact($endDate,"M/d/yy H:mm",$Null))).ToUniversalTime() -gt $([System.DateTime]::UtcNow))){
            return ("Bad")
        }
    else
        {return ("Good")}
}
```

Comment: How do we compare a datetime with current universal time. Am I doing something incorrect. It is really strange why it won't work

Comment: Are you deliberately mixing ```d``` and ```dd``` for the “day” part of your date format string?

Comment: Your `!` operations negate the `(Get-Date ...).ToUniversalTime()` part only, i.e. you're negating a `[datetime]` instance, which is always `$false`.

Comment: @mclayton a very good catch. My Input dates were a mistake. M/d/yy H:mm

Comment: @mklement0 I understood what you are saying. How do I make the whole statement as negate. As you understand I want to return bad if input date is -lt than utc date it is bad

Comment: @mklement0 bracket Issue. I see added additional bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function IsValidTimeStamp($startDate, $endDate){ 
try { (get-date) -lt $startDate -and [datetime]$startDate -lt
$enddate } catch { $false } }


get-date
Monday, March 20, 2023 2:13:58 PM

isvalidtimestamp 3/21 3/22
True

isvalidtimestamp 3/21 3/20
False

isvalidtimestamp 3/21 3/21
False

isvalidtimestamp 3/23 3/24
True

isvalidtimestamp 3/23 0/24
False
```

Comment: Nicely done; one wrinkle: If you pass invalid date strings, the function call breaks fundamentally rather than returning `$true` or `$false`. You can fix that with `function IsValidTimeStamp($startDate, $endDate){ try { (get-date) -lt [datetime] $startDate -and [datetime] $startDate -lt $enddate } catch { $false } }`. Note that use of `-as` is tempting, but `-as` actually performs _culture-sensitive_ conversions, unexpectedly - see [GitHub issue #8129](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8129).

Comment: for that TryParseExact first and return false if not parsing for the two dates. Thank You guys for all the ideas i think  i am able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing two datetime ranges there are 7 different results

[image]

Comment: Well My Input Time (start and end time) should be always greater than current Time. If not its bad time entered